# VBA class module Property Get() runs multiple times while ignoring STOP and F9 breakpoints

Tags: vba, vb6

I have a VBA class module with a `Property Get`. I'd like to debug everything via break mode, beginning from `Class_Initialize()`. I assumed the debugger would step from there into the property, but it won't. The debugger will not step into the property, and the property runs through multiple times without without being stepped into. It's not until the property is explicitly referenced by the calling module that it finally gets stepped into.

Anything in the property code which would normally trigger break mode, whether it be breakpoints or errors, is completely ignored. Furthermore, the property code runs up to **three times** this way without breaking into the debugger..!

How do I make the debugger step into the `Property Get()` from `Class_Initialize()`..?

Details, code, screenshots, & steps to repeat are below.

The code in question is basic VBA and not specific to any application, but for clarity I'll say this is being done in `Excel 2019`. An important detail is this seems to be a basic functional issue of "classic VB", because I also tested the code in `VB6` and it does the exact same thing.

The following do not trigger break mode in the property until the execution of `c = cls.Count` in the calling code:

1. Tools > Options > General > Break on all errors.
2. Step into the property with F8.
3. A breakpoint with F9.
4. The `Stop` statement.
5. `On Error` with `Err.Raise`, an error handler, and intentional divide-by-zero.

It should be noted `Debug.Print` and `MsgBox` do work. They're not the full debugger but they are options.

Below is a screenshot & code samples, and here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Copy the code samples into a standard module and class module, respectively.
2. Be sure the Locals window and Immediate window are open.
3. Run the procedure ClassDebugTest().
4. Press F8 on the first `Stop` statement.
5. Press F8 again on `Set cls = New Class1`.
6. It will step into the class and highlight `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`.
7. At the top of `Locals`, double click `Me` to expand it & view the instance variables.
8. Note the text printed in the Immediate window.
9. With F8, continue stepping out of the property, back into the calling code. The Immediate window will show the property has run three times without breaking! Why?

[image]

Standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ClassDebugTest()
    Dim cls As Class1
    Dim c As Long
    Stop
    Set cls = New Class1
    cls.Add "apples"
    cls.Add "oranges"
    cls.Add "pears"
    c = cls.Count
    Debug.Print "Class array item count is " & CStr(c) & "."
    Stop
End Sub
```

Class module "Class1":

```
Option Explicit

Private arr_data()      As Variant
Private arr_count       As Long
Private posDataNext     As Long
Private pass_count      As Long 'For testing the won't-break issue.

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Const initUpper As Long = 9
    ReDim arr_data(initUpper)
    'Other code...
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    'There's a lot going on here for testing.
    'Ultimately the last line 'Count = arr_count' will be all/most of what's left.
    pass_count = pass_count + 1
    Debug.Print "Property Get Count() has run " & CStr(pass_count) & " times."
    'Nothing below works to step into break mode until the property is explicitly
    'called from the standard module - then they all work as intended.
    Stop
    On Error GoTo errorhandler
    Debug.Print arr_data(99)
    Err.Raise 99999
    Dim divzero As Long
    divzero = 1 / 0
    'F9 on any line.
    Count = arr_count
Exit Property
errorhandler:
    Stop
    'MsgBox works ok!
    'MsgBox "Error " & CStr(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
End Property

Public Function Add(ByRef data As Variant) As Variant
    arr_data(posDataNext) = data
    arr_count = arr_count + 1
End Function
```

Comment: It's a long time since I used VB6, but there's a setting on the Tools > Options > General tab to set the Error Trapping in VB6. I always had mine set to 'Break in Class Module' and I know that I could step through Property Get and Let code without problems. I've no idea whether that applies in Vba though.

Comment: The Watch window is triggering the count. Its a weird side-effect that I've run into before. The watch window actually has the ability to edit objects, so your count is triggering and the `pass_count` is incrementing because of the watch window.

Comment: @JohnEason - VBA in many ways is identical to VB6, and it has the same Error Tapping setting. But I've tried all three choices, and the response is the same. Normally I keep it on the highest setting "Break on all errors" because I like to know what's going on.

Comment: @Toddleson but the issue is it will not step into the property. How do I get it to do that? That's the point of my OP.

Comment: I followed your instructions but didn't really understand the problem. My code was able to pause execution at every manually set breakpoint and every `Stop` command. The debug window displayed 3 messages, but like I said before, those are because the Locals window is triggering the `Count` property so it can display the value, which is causing `pass_count` to iterate, and the debug messages to send. If you close the Locals window and remove any Watches from the Watch window, these extra debug messages will disappear. and `pass_count` will be 1.

Comment: Are you asking why the Error window doesnt pop up? Is that what you mean by "not breaking"? The error window doesn't show up because you have set your own error handler `On Error GoTo errorhandler`. The error window only shows up when you have `On Error GoTo 0` (which is default)

Comment: @Toddleson when you were stopped at `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`, and then double-clicked `Me`, did the debugger jump into the property code? Or...did it step into the property at the next F8? Or was the property triggered & finished while the debugger stayed stopped at `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`..? That's what I'm trying to get at. I'd like the debugger to step into the property instead of staying stopped at `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`. But code execution runs completely through the property while the debugger is stopped at `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`.

Comment: @spinjector The watch window & locals window doesn't interrupt code execution. I dont think it would ever cause the error window to show up, or pause on Stop commands. If it can't retrieve a value it just shows the error in the watch window like "<Application-defined or object-defined error>" or "<Unable to get the ___ property of the ___ class>"

Comment: Would a manually set breakpoint set on `Stop` in the property errorhandler get hit those 3 times?

Comment: Think as Excel. I have to display a custom property value. I can get it by Property Get (user defined). This thread is mine, and don't want to stop or step through it, only display. Part two. If it workes in that way as OP, will be another post about "Why stop and step Excel in the Initialization event at my private PropertyGet?"

Comment: @StayOnTarget I've tried setting breakpoints, but they are ignored.

Comment: If your breakpoints were triggered by the watch window querying your properties, you would not be able to use the watch window for debugging. The watch window is useful in debugging your own code specifically because it does not trigger breakpoints when it queries your objects.

Comment: @Toddleson yes I've notice that, and I'm starting to understand more details. It seems the `Locals` window doesn't trigger the debugger for properties. Also, if `Me` is NOT expanded in the Locals window, the Property Get doesn't run. But it DOES run when `Me` IS expanded. Furthermore, the Property Get runs silently for every line of code the debugger executes in break mode..!!!

Comment: @Toddl Why would be triggered, if not required to display the value. Unneccessary code there are also a lot.

Answer (score 1):

At step 7, instead of expanding `Me` in the Locals window, write `?Count` in the Immediate window and press the Enter key. This will actually break on the `Stop` within the `Count` property - which is what you're expecting.

However, when the call comes from the Locals or the Watch window this doesn't happen and it was intentionally designed to behave this way. Even the `MsgBox "Error " & CStr(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description` will not display the correct value if called from the Locals/Watch window - it will display `Error 0:` instead of the expected `Error 9: Subscript out of range`.

In fact both Locals and Watch window have extra error handling that allows them to avoid crashes with GPF (General Protection Fault) errors. Basically any error is completely 'swollen' by the calls made by these 2 windows. And breaking code is simply not allowed for reasons we can only guess, like infinite call loops or security concerns.

To prove the GPF statement above, replace the code in `Class1` with this:

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Const PTR_SIZE As Long = 8
#Else
    Private Const PTR_SIZE As Long = 4
#End If
Private Const VT_BYREF As Long = &H4000

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long) As Long
    #End If
#Else 'Windows
    'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt723419(v=vs.85).aspx
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
    #Else
        Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
    #End If
#End If

Public Function TryGPF() As Long
    Dim b(0 To 10) As Byte
    Dim aPtr As LongPtr: aPtr = ArrPtr(b)
    #If Win64 Then
        Const pvDataOffset As Long = 16
    #Else
        Const pvDataOffset As Long = 12
    #End If

    MemLongPtr(aPtr + pvDataOffset) = 100 '100 is definitely not readable
    Stop
    
    Debug.Print b(0)
End Function


Public Function ArrPtr(ByRef arr As Variant) As LongPtr
    Dim vt As VbVarType
    CopyMemory vt, ByVal VarPtr(arr), 2 'VarType(arr) ignores VT_BYREF
    If vt And vbArray Then
        Const pArrayOffset As Long = 8
        ArrPtr = MemLongPtr(VarPtr(arr) + pArrayOffset)
        If vt And VT_BYREF Then ArrPtr = MemLongPtr(ArrPtr)
    Else
        Err.Raise 5, "ArrPtr", "Array required"
    End If
End Function

Private Property Get MemLongPtr(ByVal memAddress As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    CopyMemory MemLongPtr, ByVal memAddress, PTR_SIZE
End Property
Private Property Let MemLongPtr(ByVal memAddress As LongPtr, ByVal newValue As LongPtr)
    CopyMemory ByVal memAddress, newValue, PTR_SIZE
End Property
```

and the code in the standard module with this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestGPF()
    Dim c As New Class1
    c.TryGPF
End Sub
```

Now run `TestGPF`. The code will break on the `Stop` line.
Now expand `b` in the Locals window and you should see this:
[image]

So, we basically tried to read memory without having access but did not cause a GPF and a crash.

Now execute the next line `Debug.Print b(0)` by stepping through. BOOM. Application crashes.

We've just proved that the Locals window has extra handling and does not do 'regular' calls. Even the `Error 0:` message suggests these windows are operating outside of the global `Err` object, maybe even on a separate thread.

Hope this clarifies it. It's not a bug, it's a design decision.